# How to find and edit the named range that a VBA variable is referring to?

Tags: vba, excel

My work has a Macro that we use to split combined mailing addresses out into multiple columns, but it is a little sloppy. I am looking to tighten up some of the search parameters, but I am not  the one who initially wrote it so I am trying to figure some things out.

The thing I am looking at now is updating the city list in the Macro so that it will identify more cities. The trick is when I look at the Sheet that the process refers to, I cannot find an array or list with cities that the macro is checking against. It just has a bunch of sub processes that look empty to me. I am new to a lot of this so maybe I am missing something obvious.

The part of the module that references the worksheet looks like this:

```
CityList = shtCity.Range("CityList").Column
```

And the is no code in the module of the worksheet (shtCity)

I don't really know what I am looking at, so please let me know if there is any other information that I can collect to help resolve this.

Comment: "CityList" is a named range on the worksheet which has code name of `shtCity` (the name on the sheet tab may be different).  Go to that sheet, select the Formulas tab, and open the "Name Manager" dialog.  That will show you where the named range is located.  If all of those Sub's are empty then you can delete them from the sheet code module - they're not doing anything.

Comment: The `CityList = shtCity.Range("CityList").Column` is actually storing the Column number of the named range **CityList**, which may not be efficient for codes later on. You should look for codes in a normal Module, not the Sheet/ThisWorkbook module.

Comment: When you open the VBE (Alt+F11) look at the Project Explorer at the left side. If it isn't there, tap Ctrl+R to show it. Look for **+ Module** and double click it to show what module code sheets are available.

Answer (score 0):

Punch the following into the immediate window to see exactly where that range lives.

```
Debug.Print Range("CityList").Address
```

Alternative #1 - instead of using a debug.print you could put the same into a MSG box immediately before the module references that range
Alternative #2 - open shtCity and choose CTRL+F3 to see the named ranges.